# google map api nearby search how check from radius

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i'm using this code for nearby search,i have problem,how get results?

results = 0 then ,i want to check radius=1 to 1000 ,results = 1 then i want to getAddress how i do that?

```
function getAddress($la, $lo){
  $ur= "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=".$la.",".$lo."&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c";
   $json = file_get_contents($ur);

   $data = json_decode($json);
   $status = $data->status;
   $name= '';
     if($status == "OK"){
      $addr = $data->results[0]->formatted_address;
     }
   return $addr;
  } 
          echo getAddress("6.154841","80.700845");
```

Comment: When you like to get anything at all you should start by using `https://` instead of `http://`

Comment: [**`http://` (fails)**](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=6.154841,80.700845&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c) ---> [**`https://` (works)**](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=6.154841,80.700845&radius=10&sensor=true&key=AIzaSyA0JD_Z2Uo2AfnDTejQFWHAXOIaRRpjF8c)